# Check email exists: {Angular 1.5, TS, PUG}

Tags: angularjs, email

My task is to check if email exists. I have form with several input fields. One of them is email field. Once user enters and leaves the field I need to send request to check if the email exsists. If response returns true I need to enable submit button, otherwise to show error message.

I have `EmailComponent.ts`, `Email.pug` as template and angular 1.5
I am quite new in angular and need your help with this.
1) What  is the it best practice to get this task done?
2) How can I organize `checkEmail` method in my `EmailComponent.ts` to send request once user leaves the field?
3) How I can sibscribe to blur event of email input?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a directive as an attribute for your input and in that directive check after blur event that the email is available.

I don't know much about TS, but here is something i've done in JS :

```
  app.directive('checkEmail', function ($timeout, $http) {
    return {
      restrict:'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
          email: "=email"
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
          elem.on('blur', function (evt) {
              scope.$apply(function () {
                  var payload = {email: scope.email};
                  if (scope.email) {
                      $http.post('/app/v1/users/checkEmail', payload).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          ctrl.$setValidity('emailIsAvailable', true);
                      }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                          ctrl.$setValidity('emailIsAvailable', false);
                      });
                  }
              });
          });
      }
  };
});
```

What this does :

- listen to blur event on the attached elem (in my case an input field)
- on blur, calls a webservice to check if the email is available
- set 'emailIsAvailable' to true or false (that was for styling purpose)

Maybe it can inspire you.